Image not showing on complication
I'm trying to use the following as my complication code:
struct ComplicationsEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        Image("ComplicationImage")
    }
}

The image itself is a 145x145px PNG stored in my Assets catalog. The issue is that it won't load on the complication on my watch. I can see the complication and if I add something like Text("") that will show too, just images will not load.
I just want a simple complication to launch the app from a watch face.

Is the asset catalog added to your complication target?

@WarrenBurton Yes, it's targeting it.
